# The Impact of UK University Lecturing Experience on Faculty Positions in Leading Universities Abroad

Tags: professorship, university, faculty-application

Can the experience of being a university lecturer in one of the best universities in the UK enhance the chances of securing a faculty position in top universities in the USA and Australia? Additionally, do other English-speaking countries place equal or greater value on experience gained from UK universities?
PS: I do know that my personal accomplishment is the most important factor, but I want to know the reputation and importance of work experience at UK universities.

Comment: "Enhance the chances" compared to what? What would the person be doing if they didn't take a UK lecturer role?

Answer (score 4):

Given that the UK treats [Lecturers (Grade 9)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Academic_ranks_in_the_United_Kingdom) in about the same way that the US treats assistant (or even associate) professors, depending on probation, I'd say that such experience would be valued for any combined teaching/research position.

But, most hiring at US universities is at the Assistant Professor level and is for people fresh out of grad school with doctoral degrees. So, assuming that one has a doctorate and the university is willing to hire someone who is moving across universities it should be treated as a plus, equal to someone moving from one US university to another.

Some positions are open to people wanting to move up a level from assistant to associate, as well. The same should apply.

For level 10 people (Senior Lecturer) there are fewer openings and more scrutiny, but, again, the US is sophisticated enough to recognize that "Lecturer" has a different meaning in the US and in the UK.

The only information I have about Australia is that the system is similar to that of UK, so I doubt there would be an issue, but IANAA (I am not an Australian).

Answer (score 0):

I Am An Australian, and "the experience of being a university lecturer in one of the best universities in the UK" would probably be relevant to a hiring committee in the following ways:

1. It shows you have previous lecturing experience.
2. Assuming you have a decent research record, it shows you can balance lecturing and research.
3. If you have good teaching reviews (from student or faculty feedback), it shows that you're a good lecturer.

In short, it's relevant in all the usual ways and I doubt the fact that it was in the UK, and not some other country, is particularly relevant. The UK system is similar in broad strokes to the Australian system, but there are enough little local quirks that the UK experience wouldn't by itself count for more. (I've just moved, in the same city, from one university which has two teaching terms a year to one which has three -- and that's a much larger change than anything else I've ever experienced!)

Australian universities understand full well that young academics (often) move all around the world, and hiring committees will know how to look up different universities and decide what to do with a candidate's CV.

Comment: Someone working in a Japanese university vs someone working the UK/AUS has a completely different work environment experience. What you mentioned is a very minor change within the same system.